# Javascript - passing parameter to function which calls another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, settimeout

Okay my title is a bit confusing but basically, I have a function and after that function is finished executing, it should do the given steps. Here is my javascript:

```
createSideTable(showThis, function() {
    $('#' + showThis + 'Screen').slideDown('slow');
});
```

I want the createSideTable function to run all it's code before the step

```
$('#' + showThis + 'Screen').slideDown('slow');
```

can get executed. The createSideTable more or less just makes a side table fade in slowly. The function can be seen at the end of this post.
Normally, when I have a function which I want to execute all it steps and then execute other given steps, i'd do it like this

```
createSideTable(function() {
    $('#' + showThis + 'Screen').slideDown('slow');
});
```

and it works, however, the createSideTable function needs a parameter (the parameter which it needs is showThis). So when I tried

```
createSideTable(showThis, function() {
    $('#' + showThis + 'Screen').slideDown('slow');
});
```

it did create the sideTable however, this step

```
$('#' + showThis + 'Screen').slideDown('slow');
```

didn't get executed after it created the sideTable. How come?
This is my createSideTable function.

```
function createSideTable(test) {
    var key = test.substr(test.length -1); //index of Heading
    for (var i=0; i<window['headings' + key].length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            $('#row' + i).addClass('subHeadingClicked');
        }

        $('#row' + i).text('').removeClass('column1invisible');
        $('#row' + i).append(window['headings' + key][i]);
    }
    $('#sideTable').fadeIn(1500);
}
```

Comment: Is your `createSideTable` function calling the callback? Can you post that function's code?

Comment: @JasonP Hm I'm not doing a callback.. I put up the createSideTable function. How would I do a call back? Should I just add 'callback();' at the end of my createSideTable function or do I need to pass another parameter called 'callback' to the createSideTable function?

Answer (score 3):

Add the callback parameter, and if it exists, call it at the end:

```
function createSideTable(test, callback) {
    var key = test.substr(test.length -1); //index of Heading
    for (var i=0; i<window['headings' + key].length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            $('#row' + i).addClass('subHeadingClicked');
        }

        $('#row' + i).text('').removeClass('column1invisible');
        $('#row' + i).append(window['headings' + key][i]);
    }
    $('#sideTable').fadeIn(1500);

    if (callback) callback();
}
```

And you should be able to call it like this:

```
createSideTable(showThis, function() {
    $('#' + showThis + 'Screen').slideDown('slow');
});
```

Edit -

The first example was showing how a callback works. You can execute the callback where ever you want... for example, if you want it to be executed after the `fadeIn()`, you could do this:

```
function createSideTable(test, callback) {
    var key = test.substr(test.length -1); //index of Heading
    for (var i=0; i<window['headings' + key].length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            $('#row' + i).addClass('subHeadingClicked');
        }

        $('#row' + i).text('').removeClass('column1invisible');
        $('#row' + i).append(window['headings' + key][i]);
    }
    $('#sideTable').fadeIn(1500, function() {
        if (callback) callback();
    });
}
```

Comment: Why would one use a callback for that? It only might make sense to pass the callback into the `fadeIn` method.

Comment: @Bergi You're right, it was all synchronous, which doesn't make sense. My edit might make more sense.